# Favicon not displaying

Tags: html

I am developing a site in PHP. The favicon is not displaying in Chrome and IE9.

I tried is:

```
'<link rel="icon" href="../images/Favicon.ico" />'
```

which works in Firefox.

Comment: As a guess your icon file may not be properly created. Just use a png instead. Supported since IE6 and far easier to maintain than ico files.

Comment: dumb question, when you inspect the link, do you actually see the favicon? Maybe your relative url is just wrong.

Comment: Sometimes this takes a while to update from the browser "caching" it. I noticed this on a few of my website as well. My favicon wouldn't show up for almost a day.

Comment: @nfechner - he wasn't saying the question was dumb (although it can be read that way), he was saying have you thought of the easy solution first =).

Comment: @mrtsherman rather unlikely explanation as the poster stated that it works in FF

Comment: What are the single quotes for?

Answer (score 7):

There are much things that can make it not to work.

- First of all check the path if its ok. Because your path leads to some directory outside the current one (../).
- Icon file must be an icon not just image renamed to .ico
- use ctrl+f5 to refresh your browser or clean all cache and close browser and try again or even try it in some other pc
- favicon.ico should be always (the best is) in root directory

And to be sure you could use this both:

```
<link rel='icon' href='favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'> 
<link rel='shortcut icon' href='favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar issue and found that following the W3C recommendation : https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon is the best way to do this.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
```

P.S For some reason, the combination of type="image/x-icon" and href="favicon.ico" did not work for me, which is why I changed my icon to a .png file.

This works perfectly on IE11/ Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

For any favico(n), make sure in the source that it opens on a new tab / that the paths are right.
Firefox usually "just displays it". If you don't see it for Chrome - when developing locally - right-click the refresh button and from the context menu, select "Empty cache and hard-reload".